# php basic calculator with function and switch but result is

Tags: php, function, calculator

i am currently doing some simple calculator for a practice but it the output or result is not showing here is my code guys hope you can help me :/

```
    <input type="radio" value= "Addition" name="calcu"> Addition .<br />
    <input type="radio" value= "Subtraction" name="calcu"> Subtraction .<br />
    <input type="radio" value= "Multiplication" name="calcu"> Multiplication .<br />
    <input type="radio" value= "Division" name="calcu"> Division .<br />
<?php
$num1 = $_POST['num1'];
$num2 = $_POST['num2'];
$calcu = $_POST['calcu'];

    function calculate($n1,$n2)
    {
        switch('$calcu')
        {
        case "Addition";
            $compute = $n1 + $n2; 
            break;
        case "Subtraction";
            $compute = $n1 - $n2; 
            break;
        case "Multiplication";
            $compute = $n1 * $n2; 
            break;
        case "Division";
            $compute = $n1 / $n2; 
            break;
        }
    }
echo "$calcu <br /> <br /> 1st Number: $num1 <br /> 2nd Number: $num2 <br /><br />";
echo "Answer is:" .calculate($num1,$num2);
?>
```

Comment: You need to return $compute and echo calculate(...). But that's not the only problem in your code.

Comment: `'$calcu'` is not a variable, you would need to use `$calcu` but that is not be in the function's scope. Instead you have to use `$_POST['calcu']`. Also, you need to add a colon after `case`, not a semicolon.

Comment: @str passing it as argument / parameter ?

Comment: @ChristineJavier One thing I forgot that to downvote (-1) this post because it does not show any research effort or is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is complete code:

```
<?php
$num1 = $_POST['num1'];
$num2 = $_POST['num2'];
$calcu = $_POST['calcu'];

    function calculate($n1,$n2, $calcu) // set $calcu as parameter
    {
        switch($calcu)
        {
        case "Addition": // here you have to use colons not semi-colons
            $compute = $n1 + $n2; 
            break;
        case "Subtraction":
            $compute = $n1 - $n2; 
            break;
        case "Multiplication":
            $compute = $n1 * $n2; 
            break;
        case "Division":
            $compute = $n1 / $n2; 
            break;
        }
        return $compute; // returning variable
    }
echo "$calcu <br /> <br /> 1st Number: $num1 <br /> 2nd Number: $num2 <br /><br />";
echo "Answer is:" .calculate($num1,$num2, $calcu); // you need to pass $calcu as argument of that function
?>
```

Comment: finally i didn't know about adding `$calcu` as parameter :D thank you so much ;) btw its Ma'am haha thanks!

Comment: I know, I am not blind. Thanks to Allah. But still my pleasure SIR :D wrote atleast first function of PHP today.

Answer (score 0):

Change `switch('$calcu')` to `switch($calcu)`.

As @PeterM mentioned, you are accessing variable `$calcu` out of scope. Either you pass the `$calcu` variable to fun `calculate` or access directly by `$_POST` array.

use `switch($_POST['calcu'])`.

OR

```
function calculate($n1,$n2, $calcu) {
...
}
```

Call the fun by `calculate($n1,$n2, $calcu)`.

Comment: `$calcu` is not in function scope

Comment: it says undefined variable on every case sir

Comment: @PeterM Thanks for noticing the variable scope in fn.

Comment: @Justin already tried `switch($_POST['calcu'])` but nothing shows :/

Comment: @ChristineJavier you have much errors in the code e.g. Syntax.

Comment: it works now! ^_^ thanks @AspiringAqib and to others :) my homework now is done. :))

Answer (score 0):

Change `switch('$calcu')` to `switch($calcu)`. It should be this way.

But not only that. Your variables are undefined because you are trying to address them before form is submited, i.e they don't exist yet.

```
$num1 = $_POST['num1'];
$num2 = $_POST['num2'];
$calcu = $_POST['calcu'];
```

And there you address them

```
echo "$calcu <br /> <br /> 1st Number: $num1 <br /> 2nd Number: $num2 <br /><br />";
echo "Answer is:" .calculate($num1,$num2);
```

The right way to implement this is to check if form was submitted:

```
    <input type="radio" value= "Addition" name="calcu"> Addition .<br />
    <input type="radio" value= "Subtraction" name="calcu"> Subtraction .<br />
    <input type="radio" value= "Multiplication" name="calcu"> Multiplication .<br />
    <input type="radio" value= "Division" name="calcu"> Division .<br />
<?php
if (isset($_POST)){
    $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
    $num2 = $_POST['num2'];
    $calcu = $_POST['calcu'];

        function calculate($n1,$n2)
        {
            switch('$calcu')
            {
            case "Addition";
                $compute = $n1 + $n2; 
                break;
            case "Subtraction";
                $compute = $n1 - $n2; 
                break;
            case "Multiplication";
                $compute = $n1 * $n2; 
                break;
            case "Division";
                $compute = $n1 / $n2; 
                break;
            }
        }
    echo "$calcu <br /> <br /> 1st Number: $num1 <br /> 2nd Number: $num2 <br /><br />";
    echo "Answer is:" .calculate($num1,$num2);

    unset($_POST);
}
?>
```